# Determining how well a deck is shuffled

Tags: c#, random, entropy

I am doing a small poker program and I want to determine how well a deck is shuffled.
I have a List with 52 cards then I run my shuffling algorithm and I want to be able to determine how well the deck is shuffled on some scale.
Does someone have an idea how to do this?
Thanks

EDIT:
Wow. A lot of responses. All good but not exactly what I was looking for. That is my fault for not specifying my question further. But I think Saran is closest to what I actually want. Let me specify.

I do NOT want a "perfect" shuffle straight away. I already read up on that and I implemented Fisher-Yates. That one is pretty good at giving "perfect" shuffle.  What I AM trying to do is to simulate a real world situation where friends are playing texas hold-em and the dealer takes the deck and shuffles it using riffle shuffle mixed with other shuffles.
In the end, what I want is a way to measure the difference between real world shuffles.

An example. Assume the deck is always fresh (ace to king suited, then next suit ace to king  for all four suits).  Joe takes the deck and does 2 riffle shuffles with one cut in between. Peter does 5 stripping shuffles. I want to find a way to see which one shuffles the deck "better".

The more I think about it the more I think it is very very veeery hard to determine.

Thanks again.

EDIT 23.10.2013

Here is the method I came up with, combining Sarans idea with mine:

```
 public int checkShuffle(List<Card> cardDeckToCheck,int[] previousOrder)
    {
        // Higher is worse? Sure.
        int score = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < cardDeckToCheck.Count; i++)
        {
            Card cardToCheck = cardDeckToCheck[i];
            Card cardToLeft = null;
            Card cardToRight = null;

            // Should cost more since the card has not moved at all.
            // For this I need an array that shows me the arangement of the deck before shuffling.
            if(cardToCheck.index == previousOrder[i])
            {
                score += 3;
            }

            if (i == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i == 1");
                cardToRight = cardDeckToCheck[i+1];
                // if the card we are checking is one lower or one higher than the card to the right
                if(Math.Abs(cardToCheck.index - cardToRight.index) == 1)
                {
                    score++;
                }
                continue;
            }

            else if (i == cardDeckToCheck.Count-1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i == carddecktocheck.count-1");
                cardToLeft = cardDeckToCheck[i - 1];
                // if the card we are checking is one lower or one higher than 
                if (Math.Abs(cardToCheck.index - cardToLeft.index) == 1)
                {
                    score++;
                }
                continue;
            }

            else
            {
                cardToLeft = cardDeckToCheck[i - 1];
                cardToRight = cardDeckToCheck[i + 1];
                // if the card we are checking is one lower or one higher than 
                if (Math.Abs(cardToCheck.index - cardToLeft.index) == 1)
                {
                    score++;
                }
                if (Math.Abs(cardToCheck.index - cardToRight.index) == 1)
                {
                    score++;
                }
                continue;
            }

        }
        return score;
    }
```

I first record how the deck looks like into an int array then I shuffle the deck and then I run this method with the shuffled deck and the previous order of the deck.
Like so:

```
int[] previousOrder = getCurrentOrder(deck.getDeck());
deck.setDeck(riffleShuffle2(3));
textBoxShuffleness.Text = "" + checkShuffle(deck.getDeck(), previousOrder);
displayDeck(deck);
```

When I start with an unshuffled deck and run the riffle shuffle method 5 times I get 70,33,28,5,10. 
When I start with an unshuffled deck and run the Durstenfeld shuffle method 5 times I get
5,0,7,11,7.

Those results are very much what I would expect.

If someone can find something wrong with this method then I would appreciate if you would comment :)
Thanks

Comment: And what scale would that be? You could shuffle the deck a gazillion times and end up with the exact same order.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp

Comment: If randomness can be measured, it's not good randomness.

Comment: Sure, define some criteria and probe against them. Reading about probability distribution and probability density will be a good starting point.

Comment: I flagged this question to be moved to a sister forum about math, where you can ask about measurements of randomness. Once you know what specific measurement you want to use, we can help you find a tool to perform that measurement here at StackOverflow =)

Comment: @nmclean - can you explain what you comment mean? Do you consider for example computing "average (or deviation,...) of 1000 random numbers" as measuring randomness ?

Comment: This is really more of a mathematics question.  If you get the approaches to measuring randomness from here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions  and then need help knowing how to implement it, then stackoverflow would be more on point for you.

Comment: Knuth has a whole chapter on testing and measuring the quality of "randomness" in tAoCP.

Comment: fun article on shuffling http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea for this would be to take the list and populate it with integer values (1 int per card). Make another set of code that takes the int value and converts it into your card value, so you retain which cards belong to which numbers. Randomize the list of integers and then loop through each line in the list and mark how many are within a set of ranges or one range of 1-2 integers from the previous number. At then end, you then set a set of percentage scale for Poor, Good, Great, ect...

This may not be the best solution, but you will be able to have an idea on how spread out the list is.

Comment: I think you might be on to something. 
So what you are saying is that if a card from my real deck is far away from its original position then that is an indication of good shuffle while if it is within a certain threshold of its original position then it is an indication of a bad shuffle. Right?

Comment: Sorta, you can always go with it at that way as well. My original idea is the take the list after it is shuffled and iterate through the list comparing each line item to the next. If they are spread out, meaning the int is not within 1-2 integers (1 + 1 or 1 + 2) then the shuffle is good. (item 1 = int 10, item 2 = int 30, difference of 20 ints).

Comment: Ahh yes. I see. I will try to implement both of these tests. 
For now I will leave this question unanswered...

Comment: Sorry for so late answer but I have been busy.
So I implemented a method in my program that checks how well a deck is shuffled. It builds on Sarans idea and it works pretty well as far as I can see.
It outputs an integer and the higher that integer is the worse shuffled deck I have. 0 is a "perfect" shuffle score.
I will mark Sarans answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 7):

To have any hope, you would need to run your shuffling program over and over, always starting with the same initial deck, and compare the results.

If it is completely fair, you expect that any given card has a 1-in-52 chance of ending up in any spot after shuffling.

If there is bias, you'd see that it ends up in some spots more frequently than others.

Of course, some variation from the ideal 1-in-52 is expected.
The amount of variation that is acceptable is predictable by stats and various confidence intervals. (95%?  97%?)

And even if you got a perfect distribution, that doesn't mean your shuffling is random.
*(Imagine a shuffle-algorithm that simply rotates the deck by one card on each successive shuffle.... it would have perfect 1-in-52 results, but wouldn't be at all random)*

Another aspect to look for is correlation between cards.
For example, the final location of the Ace-of-Spades and the King-of-Spades should be completely uncorrelated.
A bad shuffling algorithm could move those two cards around together, resulting in high correlation.
Checking for the correlation of every card against every other card is computationally expensive, but should be a simple algorithm.

I think the end result is that you cannot prove your algorithm is a fair/good shuffle.
You can only set up various tests to look for "bad" shuffles (non-uniform distribution, or high correlations of card positions).  If you pass all the tests for bad-shuffles, it doesn't mean your algorithm is not flawed in some other way that the tests didn't cover.
But it does give you increasing confidence.

There may be an even better way to test for randomness, but it is [computationally impossible](http://czep.net/weblog/52cards.html).

As the [Coding Horror Blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) entry points out, a far better way may be to run your algorithm against very small decks of cards (the article uses a 3-card deck), and carefully evaluate those results.   With only 3 cards it should be much easier to trace all paths, and see if all outcomes are equally likely.

Answer (score 3):

Some info here: [Randomness tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests). It is worth noting that if your shuffle "passes" all such tests, it's just an indication that the shuffle might be truly random. However, if you're using a pseudo-random generator, you already know that it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot measure how well single deck is shuffled, since every cards combination is equally probable.

However, you can measure how good your shuffling algorithm really is. Jeff Atwood has some posts about this particular problem:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html